# Scroll в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Вопрос в следующем: написал код для скролинга страницы, на большом экране работает нормально, на телефоне - плохо. Что делать?

Сам код:

```js
var how_many_to_scroll = Math.ceil((elheight + 20 - window.pageYOffset)/20);

var interval_log = setInterval(
 function () {
  window.scrollBy(0,how_many_to_scroll);
 }, 15);
  
setTimeout (
 function () {
  clearInterval(interval_log);
 }, 300);
```

elHeight берётся отсюда:

```js
var elheight = document.getElementById("second").scrollHeight;
```

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста подробнее, что вы подразумеваете под фразой "на телефоне плохо"? Не скролится? Или скролится рывками? Или как?

Comment: @ДанилЧугаев скролится не до того места, которое нужно